# В уголку консольное время

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать в уголку экрана время которое постоянно обновляется, но при этом чтобы работала основная программа.
Программа это простая менюшка.
Не знаю куда можно прописать DateTime с бесконечным циклом которое бы обновляла время и не мешала работе самой программы

```
        Console.Clear();

        int top = Console.CursorTop;
        int y = top;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("*Авторизоваться");
        Console.WriteLine("*Войти как покупатель");

        int down = Console.CursorTop;
        ConsoleKey Key;
        Console.CursorSize = 100;
        Console.CursorTop = top;
        while ((Key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key) != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            if (Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                if (y > top)
                {
                    y--;
                    Console.CursorTop = y;
                }
                else
                if (y >= top && Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    y = y + 2;
                    Console.CursorTop = top;
                }
            }
            if (Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                if (y < down - 1)
                {
                    y++;
                    Console.CursorTop = y;

                }
                else
                if (y <= down - 1 && Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                {
                    y = y - 2;
                    Console.CursorTop = top;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: можно попробовать по циклу менять тайтл консоли. потому что придется использовать winapi, если хотите прямо так обновлять консоль. и тут не в две-три строчки решение, а полноценная работа с консолью по средствам функций winapi (естественно будет работать только под windows)

Comment: зачем пытаться делать интерфейс в консоли. Делайте сразу приложение с нормальным интерфейсом (например, WPF)

Comment: Можно [олдскульно](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs)